# pnpm Vite ENOENT

Tags: vite, pnpm

I'm trying to install Vite related modules with pnpm. I used the `pnpm create vite` command. It didn't work so I deleted the node modules folder and ran `pnpm store prune`. I reinstalled and found it was the same problem. It appears to be triggered by this dependency.

```
.pnpm\@types+react@18.2.14\node_modules\csstype
Full error
 ENOENT  ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '\my_app\node_modules\.pnpm\@types+react-dom@18.2.6\node_modules\@types\csstype'
```

Not sure what to do next as pnpm is new to me and I don't usually struggle to install Vite with npm.

Node: 18.14.2
pnpm: 8.6.7